# Data extract error: [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ':'. (102)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, postgresql, execute

I am trying to extract data from SQL Server and load it into PostgreSQL. The SQL query runs fine in SQL Server, the connection doesn't seem to be the problem.

the following error message is:

> Data extract error: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ':'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

```
# import needed libraries
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os

# get password from environmnet var
pwd = os.environ['PGPASS']
uid = os.environ['PGUID']
# sql db details
driver = "{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}"
server = "DESKTOP-7CS8HNG"
database = "AdventureWorksDW2019;"


# extract data from sql server
def extract():
    try:
        src_conn = pyodbc.connect(
            'DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' + server + '\SQLEXPRESS' + ';DATABASE=' + database +
            ';UID=' + uid + ';PWD=' + pwd)
        src_cursor = src_conn.cursor()
        # execute query
        src_cursor.execute(""" select t.name as table_name
        from sys.tables t where t.name in ('DimProduct','DimProductSubcategory',
        'DimProductSubcategory','DimProductCategory','DimSalesTerritory','FactInternetSales') """)
        src_tables = src_cursor.fetchall()
        for tbl in src_tables:
            # query and load save data to dataframe
            df = pd.read_sql_query(f'select * from {tbl[0]}', src_conn)
            load(df, tbl[0])
    except Exception as e:
        print("Data extract error: " + str(e))
    finally:
        src_conn.close()


# load data to postgres
def load(df, tbl):
    try:
        rows_imported = 0
        engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{uid}:{pwd}@{server}:5432/AdventureWorks')
        print(f'importing rows {rows_imported} to {rows_imported + len(df)}... for table {tbl}')
        # save df to postgres
        df.to_sql(f'stg_{tbl}', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
        rows_imported += len(df)
        # add elapsed time to final print out
        print("Data imported successful")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Data load error: " + str(e))


try:
    # call extract function
    extract()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error while extracting data: " + str(e))
```

Comment: Can you show us the problem SQL separately.

Comment: Is there are reason you're still using the SQL Server Native Client as well? That was discontinued *many* years ago (about 9 years ago), and doesn't support any of the "recent" SQL Server versions.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a table that contains a ":" in it?
If you change so you fetch quoted tables names it should work:

select QUOTENAME(t.name) as table_name

Comment: @siggemannen - the WHERE clause shows us the possible table names and none of them contain a `:`. But somehow a `:` seems to be entering the SQL Strings from the error message

Comment: Oh right, i didn't see the where condition. Perhaps tbl[0] is not a string but a dictionary so it gets printed as {"name":value} It's probably easy to print the sql before running to see what it is

Comment: Also, @jmyauy, you should actually write if error is in "load" or in "extract"

Comment: @Larnu It was a part of a online course that I was taking